# 你 <verb phrase> 你

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I have been watching a TV show set in Beijing where many of the characters keep saying things like `你別打狗了你` (probably a bad example), putting a seemingly redundant `你` at the end. What is this used for? Is it used outside of Beijing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is widely used across China, but I think it is mainly used in the northern part of China, maybe Beijing, I'm not sure.

`你...你` in this case is not different from simply using `你...`, but `你...你` could express a stronger tone, or willing.

e.g. `你別打狗了` vs `你別打狗了你`, both of them mean `Don't beat that dog`, but the last one is more urgent and anxious.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, 你别打狗了你 is more emphatic than just one 你, and you might hear it occasionally in spoken. It connotes that I won't allow you to do so or expressing imperative.

There is another similar expression that puts the subject into the end of a sentence. For example, 别走了你.